# .htaccess mobile redirect issues

Tags: htaccess, redirects, mobile

I'm trying to set up a mobile redirect for a site with 2 subfolders, and I cannot get both to work at the same time.

This is the structure of the site

- `www.example.com/EN/`
- `www.example.com/ES/`

This is a bilingual site so each subfolder contains the files corresponding to each language version. Then I was using a 301 redirect, and setting up the index in `/EN/` as the main index. Everything was getting redirected to it. I was using:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
Redirect /index.html http://www.example.com/EN/index.html
```

and several `RewriteCond` to redirect `example.com` and old URLs to the new URL.

It worked fine before I decided to add a mobile version to `m.example.com`.

I used the solution provided in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680463/mobile-redirect-using-htaccess, and it redirects my mobile version properly, but now the desktop is both working. Besides, my mobile version must be bilingual as well.

---

I'll do my best to clarify.

My site is bilingual. I've created two subfolders (`EN` and `ES`) to hold the contents for each language.

My desktop site requires some kind of redirect to find the right index (one of them at least, so I decided to set the English language version as the main index). The script I used is as stated above.

Now, when I added mobile detection redirect (and it does take me to the mobile version on a mobile device), it seems to go to the usual default index on the desktop (`www.example.com/index.html`) which is *not* **my** desktop index.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. When you say "the desktop is both working" do you mean "not working"?

Answer (score 2):

From the link you have provided ..

```
# Now redirect to the mobile site
RewriteRule ^ http://m.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

If you are using the  the **L** flag, it mean LAST rule to process, so you can have surprises with further rules :-)

You may also want to use other rules for your mobile/desktop version to redirect to the EN subdir by default instead of using the Redirect command. However, i think the problem here is just your rules order in the htaccess combined with the L flag.